# Set selected items of multiple-select object in Laravel 4

Tags: php, html, dom, laravel, laravel-4

My project is about shops belongs to many sections.
When creating a shop, sections are chosen (selected) in a multi-select list and values are saved correctly. Also when editing the info, user can save changes correctly. The problem is that: in edit form multi-select object is clear (no items are selected at all) while we need to set options to be selected according to the pre-saved data, so user can see and modify it.

in controller I select lists like this:

```
 public function edit($id)
{    
    $data  = Shops::with('sections')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
    $sectionslst = Sections::lists('section_name','id'); 
    return View::make('admin.shops.edit')->with('data',$data)
                    ->with('sectionslst', $sectionslst );
}
```

and I populate data in my view this way

```
{{Form::label('shop_section','الاقسام') }}
    {{ Form::select('shop_sections[]', $sectionslst, array (1, 2), array ('multiple' => 'multiple' ))}}

//I'm using array(1, 2) just to try how it works, but it doesn't, all items still un-selected  :-(
```

Comment: Can you show us a dump of `$sectionlst` please?

Comment: I edited my question. Plz, chk it again. @lukasgeiter

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I meant. Make a `var_dump($sectionlst)` and then please copy paste the output here instead of a screenshot. Also what  exact version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using latest version 4.2.
The results are:

Comment: array(37) { [13]=> string(10) "ملابس" [14]=> string(23) "ملابس-نسائية" [15]=> string(21) "ملابس_رجالي" [16]=> string(21) "ملابس_اطفال" [18]=> string(10) "احذية" [19]=> string(10) "مطاعم" [20]=> string(14) "مجوهرات" [23]=> string(12) "عطورات" [25]=> string(27) "مستحضرات تجميل" [28]=> string(10) "ساعات" [29]

Comment: Editing your question would have been better, but I think I see the problem... You don't even have the ids `1,2`! Try `array(13,14)` instead

Comment: Thanks. That is absolutely right. Could you, Plz, tell me how to use my $data->sections instead of static array('13', '14').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you obviously can't use `array(1,2)` to test it if you don't have those id's in your list. Instead:

```
{{ Form::select('shop_sections[]', $sectionslst, array(13, 14), array ('multiple' => 'multiple' ))}}
```

Now the real problem here is that `$data->sections` is an Eloquent collection of models. However `Form::select` expects an array of keys. You can fix that by using `lists()`

```
$data->sections->lists('id')
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It works perfectly. But I needed to tweak it a bit 
$data[0]->sections->lists('id').

Comment: Or better, use `first()` instead of `get()` or even `find($id)`

Comment: I thought about it. But I'm afraid it returns only one section only.